# NSUserDefaults not printing ExactValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Hi i am very new for ios and in my project i am using NSuserDEfaults

but when i retrive int value i am not getting exact value, i am getting like  "383252368" in NSLog statement

please help me some one how can i get exact value

my code:-

### for saving:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSUserDefaults *def =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [def setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"index"];

}
```

### for retriving:-

```
  NSUserDefaults *def =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  int index = [def integerForKey:@"index"];
```

Comment: What value did u store?

Comment: int value i am storing

Comment: NSLog(@"index value is %d",index); in that way i am printing

Comment: `indexPath.row` is an `NSUInteger` not an `NSInteger`. You want to cast it to an `NSInteger` before saving it.

Comment: how can i cast them expalin please

Comment: `[def setInteger:(NSInteger)indexPath.row forKey:@"index"]`

Comment: how can i retrive that value

Comment: no use same respose is coming again

Comment: after setting value dont forget to syncronize.  `[def syncronize];` probably it will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

**Save like:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int index = indexPath.row;
[userDefaults setInteger:index forKey:@"index"];
```

**Retrieve like:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger loadrows = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"index"];
```

**EDIT**

Better you save it in array:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   int index = indexPath.row;
   [mutableArray addObject:index];
 }
```

Then Retrive:

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in mutableArray) {
    NSLog(@"index : %d",indexPath);
}
```

Comment: no not working still same response printing like 375725584

Comment: where are you retriving values from nsuserdefaults?

Comment: i am storing when user click on tableList row and retriving at another class

Comment: so those numbers represent each index of row, which  you have added in userdefaults

Comment: yes i am adding those number and retriving where i want

Comment: I meant, what is your expected output?? The way u r getting it , its right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103370/discussion-between-abhiram-and-ianurag).

Answer (score 0):

For Saving

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"index"];
```

For Retreiving

```
   NSInteger row = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"index"];
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)

Another way for this

Saving

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:@"index"];
```

Retreiving

```
   NSInteger row = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"index"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the saving itself. After you set the value, you have to call

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

This method ensures that the variable will be available for fetching in other view controllers. If this is not set, then parallel access of the variable will result in some junk.unknown values.